# External Access to Sharepoint 365 Site

Tags: asp.net, ad, membership

My organization has a ASP.Net Extranet site that uses the standard .NET SQL membership provider DB using forms authentication, and we also have a Sharepoint site on Office 365 for our internal users that points to our AD. We are looking at strategies to give our Extranet users access to this 365 Sharepoint site. We can use the external sharing feature built into 365 but this would create a continuous manual process because our Extranet users are a rotating group. What other options, if any, do we have?

In addition to the ASP.NET Extranet site we also provide our External users with email accounts through office 365. We have approximately 20 groups of Extranet users currently and they are all in separate 365 tenants. Our 365 Sharepoint site is of course on a separate tenant from these External tenants.  Would it be easier to give our users access to our Sharepoint site through their 365 accounts (rather than the .net membership db for our Extranet site) and if so what is the best way to accomplish? Keeping in mind that our Sharepoint site is in a separate tenant.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the native sharing capabilities of Office 365 to share the site with your external users. You want to make sure the site collection(s) are set to

> Allow external users who accept sharing invitations and sign in as
>   authenticated users

This will send them a sharing link and let them sign in with any Office 365 account or any Microsoft account (like live.com).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Eric. We had hoped to find a more seamless solution than the native sharing option because we have a somewhat large and rotating group of external users. Is there a way to automate the sharing process in any way? Or is pasting in a delimited string of email addresses the only option?